# React and JavaScript - binding functions explained

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.name = 'MyComponent';

    this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick1() {
    alert(this.name);
  }

  handleClick3 = () => alert(this.name);
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1()}>click 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1}>click 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick2}>click 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick3}>click 4</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And i was wondering why each button works the way that it does.

1) click 1 - nothing is displayed when i click on it, why?
If i change it to `{() => this.handleClick1()}` it gives me the `alert` with `MyComponent`.

2) click2 - gives me an empty `alert`. My assumptions is that's because `this` in `handleClick1()` isn't bound to anything. Is that correct?

3) click3 - gives me the `alert` with `MyComponent`. My assumptions is that's because now `handleClick1()` is bound to `this` and so it has access to `this.name`. Is that correct?

4) click4 - gives me the `alert` with `MyComponent`. My assumptions is that's because arrow functions can access the `this` of where they are defined. Is that correct?

Comment: "*click 1 - nothing is displayed when i click on it*" - but certainly you realise that something is displayed when the component is rendered?

Comment: "*click2 - My assumptions is that's because this in handleClick1() isn't bound to anything*" - no. Try `alert(this)` instead. Notice that if it was `undefined`, you would have gotten an exception about accessing its `.name` property.

Comment: @Bergi so what's the reason for click2? and what about click3 and click4?

Comment: As for 3 and 4 your assumptions are correct, arrow functions in classed are auto bound to the instance of the class.

Comment: Ok, so for click2 i imagine it's bound to `this`, but not the same `this` as the instance of the class and that's why `this.name` is `undefined?

Comment: I'm quite sure click 2 would cause an error, create-react-app will add `"use strict";` so it can't be `window` which it would be when not in strict mode.